# Unable to delete files using the script

Tags: command-line, bash, permissions, scripts, cron

After a long search, trial and error, I created a script

```
#!/bin/bash

find /home/SHARE/temp/* -mtime +10 -exec rm {} \;
```

When created, it was executed and deleted all files older than 10 days but left the folders in which these files were lying.

I wrote it down in cron and now I see that it does nothing.

Maybe I wrote it incorrectly in cron, but when I try to execute it manually, I get the:

`rm query: remove write-protected regular file`

and asks to confirm the deletion, and after that says

`Permission denied`

How to make that not only files but also folders are deleted?

How to automatically run a script with rights sudo?

Thank you for your help

Comment: `rm -rf` instead of only `rm`

Comment: I would just use `-f` and NOT `-rf`, because otherwise you could possibly accidentally remove whole directories recursively containing files you did not want to delete...

Comment: In cron you will likely need two backslashes instead of one.

Comment: To delete empty directories without deleting /home/SHARE/temp itself use `find /home/SHARE/temp/* -type d -empty -exec rmdir {} \;`  And you could include "-type f" in your existing find command so that it only attempts to remove files, leaving the directories to be removed by my command above.

Comment: Thank you for your help
Added the `-type f` and second line of deleting empty folders - it works.

Now you need to check that it works from cron. Under `sudo su` works, only time to issue a message `No such file or directory`  Whether it is possible to avoid it or this small evil?

Comment: The "No such file or directory" is doubtless due to the shell attempting to expand "/home/SHARE/temp/*".  This can be avoided by redirecting stderr, for example with "2> /dev/null" at the end of the line.  Alternatively reduce the path to "/home/SHARE/temp".  As for cron and sudo I will leave that to you to research.  The Question/Answer forum is best served by a singular question, rather than several on different topics.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To delete empty directories below but not including /home/SHARE/temp use

```
find /home/SHARE/temp -depth -mindepth 1 -type d -empty -exec rmdir {} \;
```

To delete only files in your original command include `-type f` thus

```
find /home/SHARE/temp -type f -mtime +10 -exec rm {} \;
```

If using these commands from cron replace `\;` with `\\;`

Comment: When the directory is not empty `rmdir` will not succeed, but we can use `rm -R` instead. Additionally use `sudo the-script-file.sh` or when it is a cronjob use root's crontab: `sudo crontab -e` - there we don't need `sudo` command.

Comment: I forgot the -depth option when deleting empty directories.  This will start at the deepest directory and work its way back up the tree.  I've edited it in to the find command above.  Note that this is a two stage process - first delete old files, then tidy up empty directories.

Answer (score 1):

i believe you need to force remove a file as the file is read only by modifiying the line:

```
find /home/SHARE/temp/* -mtime +10 -exec rm {} \;
```

to

```
find /home/SHARE/temp/* -mtime +10 -exec "rm -f" {} \;
```

In addition to this you would enjoy executing the script using the root user.